# ValidationError: Progress Plugin Invalid Options

Tags: angular, command-line-interface, angular-ui-bootstrap

[image: error while running angular cli]When I run my project from angular cli. it shows me this error. (image attached).

I have updated my node_module files and search around many other platforms but...

```
options should NOT have additional properties
options should pass "instanceof" keyword validation
options should match exactly one schema in oneOf

ValidationError: Progress Plugin Invalid Options

options should NOT have additional properties
options should pass "instanceof" keyword validation
options should match exactly one schema in oneOf[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: Try ```npm update``` in terminal, per this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69207533/1459653

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error shows up when @angular-devkit/build-angular is old version (in my case it was 0.8.0), I upgraded it to a newer version 0.13.7 and it worked.
And to avoid continuous issues while builing your application please makesure that webpack version is >=4.29

Answer (score 7):

This happened to me due to mismatch of the webpack and angular cli versions on my machine. Try to downgrade webpack to version "4.24.0" for your project. Easiest way to do so is to add specific version of webpack as dev-dependency in package.json:

```
devDependencies": {
    ...
    "webpack": "4.24.0",
    ...
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem, or at least get me to another error message :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, I solved it by updating the version of node.js because I had an old version

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34545259)

Answer (score -5):

Fixed it with removing colors option on this file:
/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/common.js
on Line: 123

Changed this:

```
extraPlugins.push(new ProgressPlugin({ profile: buildOptions.verbose, colors: true }));
```

to:

```
extraPlugins.push(new ProgressPlugin({ profile: buildOptions.verbose }));
```

Comment: I downvoted because changing code by hand under `node_modules` is never a valid option: you cannot share this edit with coworkers and you’ll lose it every time you upgrade the dependency or reset your `node_modules` directory.